# Class argument is invalid:

Tags: magento2

> 1 exception(s): Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Class
>   argument is invalid:
>   Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context
>   Class argument is invalid: Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context
>   when i disable below code its worked fine

```
 <argument name="context" xsi:type="configurableObject">
    <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context</argument>
    <argument name="namespace" xsi:type="string">productattach_grid_index</argument>
</argument>
```

Comment: Please provide more context, e.g. a stacktrace

Comment: where you face above error? what you have try to implement?

Comment: when i am trying to open grid in admin of custom module

Comment: can you see my question edit

Answer (score 3):

If you delete the following block from the UI Component xml file, things appear to be working normally for me:

```
<argument name="context" xsi:type="configurableObject"> <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context</argument> <argument name="namespace" xsi:type="string">prince_faq_index</argument> </argument>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can delete below block from your extension then it's working fine.
app/code/Prince/Productattach/view/adminhtml/ui_component/productattach_grid_index.xml

```
<argument name="context" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Context</argument>
        <argument name="namespace" xsi:type="string">productattach_grid_index</argument>
    </argument>
```

Also, you can not delete then find other way but it's fetch the error, I will share solution as soon as.

just add to app/etc/di.xml

> ```
> <item name="2" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface</item>
> ```

```
 <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Argument\Interpreter\ConfigurableObject">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="classWhitelist" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="0" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface</item>
                <item name="1" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProviderInterface</item>
                <item name="2" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

Comment: Adding that extra item to the `app/etc/di.xml` file appears to have worked but I have 2 questions.
1) will that file get overridden during the next magento upgrade?
2) what does that section do, what is the whiteList?

thanks